# Multiple routes in node.js and URL endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.use('/api', require('./api'));
app.use('/', require('./cms'));
```

The first route is for my public api, the second is the cms dashboard. But this will not work, because localhost:80/api will still load the second route too.

How to solve this? I know I can do `app.use('/cms', require('./cms'));` but the route would be localhost:80/cms/blog which is not fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the function you pass to the app.use has 3 parameters, the third one being next() callback, which calls the next middleware.

If you define your function as below, and don't call next, then it shouldn't trigger the next middleware( route too perhaps ).

```
app.use('/api', function(req, res, next) {
    require('./api');
});
```

Whatever your require'd file contains, it probably receives the "next" function as its parameter. Dont call it.

update: Also, in your middleware , call res.end() to quit other routes

Comment: in the cms routes there's lot of stuff going on, it's better to separate them. This doesn't quite work, because I have a auth check middleware for all the cms routes.

Comment: Also, in your middleware , call res.end() to quit other routes

Comment: call that before res.json or res.render?

Answer (score 0):

What's in your ./cms file? It might be that the server isn't closing the response, so it continues on to the next route.

Comment: auth check using passport.